# List comprehension produces wrong values

Tags: python

I have a list of many values which i need to get rid of some values.
I want to get from all elements that don't fit. I need to have elements only in range(x, y).
I tried this:
`K = [v > x and v < y for v in L]`
However I get a list of `True` and `False` values...
How can I achieve that ?

Example:

```
L = [4, 5, 7]
range = [4, 6]
K = [5]
```

Comment: Is L an ordered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
`K = [v for v in L if v > num1 and v < num2]`
```

**Option 2:**

```
`K = filter(lambda x: x > num1 and x < num2, L)`
```

You should have added the `if` otherwise you will get the boolean results...

Comment: @Shaked
Note: you could do also `K = [ v for v in L if num1 < v < num2]`

Comment: @Shaked Yes you should do  use `num1 < v < num2`. As I said, Python chains the comparisons so it's the same as using `and`

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get booleans is you're returning the result of the comparison rather than the value. Also Python chains the comparisons so you don't need to use `and`:

`K = [v for v in L if x < v < y]`

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a > b` is a boolean expression, which can be `True` or `False`, and moreover, you are taking the `logical AND` of two boolean expressions, and thats why you get a list of `True` and `False`. If want to get the values in a given range, do this :

```
K = [i for i in L if (i > range[0] and i < range[1])]
```